# mvc form method='post' with two submit buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, form-submit, submit-button

I've reviewed several posts here for a solution. I'll try a fresh question.

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Manage")"  data-cs-ajax="true" data-cs-target="#catalogList" >
```

It has an auto complete field and paging, very similar to the OdeToFood example from Scott Allen.

There is :

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
```

which updates some filtered items to selected from - all works great - and also:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
```

They both successfully hit:

```
//POST: /WebCatalog/Manage/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Manage")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Manage([Bind(Include = "Id,CatalogId,CatalogColourId,CatalogSizeId,CatalogCategoryId,CatelogSupplierId,StartDate,EndDate,Active,isSubmitted")] WebCatalogViewModel model, string searchTerm = null, int page = 1)
    { ...
```

They do hit the controller action because of the javascript:

```
$(function () {

var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-cs-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        var options = {};
        $newHtml.effect("highlight", options, 500, doneEffect);
    });

    return false;
};
```

Now...

I want to set a field in the model to let the controller know the second btnSave button was clicked...to save the record, of course....

Soo...

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnSave").click(function () {

        $("isSubmitted").val("1");
        return true;
    });

});
```

And that fires: before the page is submitted via ajax in ajaxFormSubmit, the button jQuery code for $(#btnSave") does successfully fire.

However, in the controller action, isSubmitted is always 0.

I've tried :

```
$("isSubmitted").val(1);
```

I've tried the form as method='get' and still no post - although, I might try to then change the method with javascript in the btnSave.click js function  - not sure how to do that...if I can't save a value in a form control, then why would I be able to change the form method??

I've tried an $Ajax.ActionLink - but always get a 500 IIS error.

Basically, I need a way to know that the user clicked the save button, rather than the Update button.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: It seems the selector in $("isSubmitted") is missing, e.g. `$("#isSubmitted")` for an input with an id isSubmitted.

Comment: @NoGray - can you please add this as an answer? I owe you a beer. No, two. That was it. Perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robert Achmann, here is my answer

It seems the selector in $("isSubmitted") is missing, e.g. $("#isSubmitted") for an input with an id isSubmitted.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a hidden value to tell the controller which button was clicked. What you need to do is name the 2 buttons as follow

```
<input type="submit" name="btnAction" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
<input type="submit" name="btnAction" value="Save" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-default" />
```

As you can see, they have the same name but different values (update vs save).

In the controller, add another parameter called `btnAction`, which is the name of the buttons, to the action.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Manage")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Manage(string btnAction, [Bind(Include = "Id,CatalogId,CatalogColourId,CatalogSizeId,CatalogCategoryId,CatelogSupplierId,StartDate,EndDate,Active,isSubmitted")] WebCatalogViewModel model, string searchTerm = null, int page = 1)
{
     if(btnAction.ToLower() == "save")
     {
          // The save button was clicked
     }
     else if(btnAction.ToLower() == "update")
     {
          // The update button was clicked
     }
     else
     {
          // default ...
     }
}
```

Basically, the parameter `btnAction` will get the value of the submit button triggering the form to get post.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look at this too - it may be simpler to manage this way.

Comment: No joy. If I add the name="btnAction" to both submit controls, add the string parameter btnAction to the Controller Action, and try to test the value of the btnAction value it's always null. Can't mark this as answer unless there's a work around. I know you can name radio buttons in a similar fashion, but it doesn't seem to work for submit buttons.

Comment: uhmm, I see, because you ajaxify the form using `serialize()`, which doesn't collect button values. If you use `Ajax.BeginForm()` in Razor, my solution will work. I'd recommend using `@using(Ajax.BeginForm(...))` because you don't have to take care of how the form is submitted in js unless you have other reasons to do so. Just a curiosity, how do you call the `ajaxFormSubmit` function?

Comment: Towards the end of my doc ready                                   jQuery: $(function () {
, after all my functions, I have:                                           $("form[data-cs-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);                    and in my form, if I want to take advantage of this ability, I add the data-cs-ajax='true' data- attribute to my form definition.

Comment: I do .serialize() because I thought you should post to the server in the same manner that you expect back (json) when on the client side. Is that a correct assumption? "I'm the client, so I only speak json..." sort of mantra...

Comment: Well, Json is an easy and light way of making an ajax call from js. For me, whether you post and receive in the same datatype isn't a matter as long as it is easy to implement and it has to be considerably faster than the other.

Comment: uhmmm... so when they click btnSave, isSubmmitted becomes 1. What happens if they click btnSave and then click btnUpdate? Will the isSubmitted remain as 1 or turn to 0?

Comment: No, I take care of IsSubmitted in server logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could a hidden field in your form to store the value of what field was clicked (controlling this with jquery event handlers) , and for this you could make your button type="button" instead of type="submit" (in order to submit your form from your Jquery code) or you could use eventPreventDefault.

Well, here is a code sample that might help you:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#bt1").click(function(){
        alert(' Save button');
        $("#operation").val('save');
        $("#frm").submit();
      });

      $("#bt2").click(function(){
        alert(' Update button');
        $("#operation").val('update');
        $("#frm").submit();
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <form id="frm">
        <div id="div1"><h2> Form buttons - What of then was clicked? </h2></div>
        <button id="bt1"> Save button </button>
        <button id="bt2"> Update button </button>
         <input type="hidden" id="operation" name="operation" value=""/>
        </form>     
        </body>
        </html>
```